# can a machine ai hallucinate?

Tags: artificial-intelligence, reality, subjectivity

It seems to me our current experience of the subjective consciousness of a human is currently based on the one of the following:
- reporting of the subjective experience through language
- observation of electrical activity in brain areas mapped to subjective experience
Using those 2 as the recognition of ongoing subjective experience and with materialists like Dennett defining the processing that occurs in the brain as the subjective experience itself, how long before AI can claim they have machines 'experiencing subjective reality'?
After all, we have machines that can input,store and process the objective reality. It can always be claimed that the monitored processing of information in the form of electrical activity is the evidence of the machine experiencing a subjective reality since, besides language, that is the only evidence we have for it in the case of other humans due to the problem of Other Minds.

The only argument I can think to this is to show if machines can hallucinate. There is strong evidence to show that the majority of humans when exposed to sensory deprivation will experience some form of visual or auditory hallucination. Essentially, in the *absence* of sensory data, the mind will generate false data. If the machine AI does this then maybe they are truly experiencing subjective reality.....

Comment: You need a stronger sense of what 'hallucinate' means.  To some degree (https://braindecoder.com/post/up-to-90-of-your-perception-could-be-made-up-purely-by-the-brain-1104633927), our entire perceptual mechanism is a hallucination that is checked by reality inputs.  No inputs, means no checking, and a more bizarre hallucination.  More input means more checks and a more realistic one.  But there is no discontinuous point where something is 'just unrealistic enough' to be a hallucination.

Comment: I essentially mean audio/visual experience in the objective world that does not exist there. In the case of the machine, I am willing to reduce it to observation of electrical output when there is no input where there is electrical output when there IS input. But maybe this question should be closed as some users have suggested. Hypothesized on unconstructed structures although I thought that was philopsophy was about.

Comment: But the combination of green and red to make yellow is a visual experience of the objective world that does not exist there.  There is no radiation of the wavelength of yellow created by combining the two other colors.  If that is a hallucination, then our notion of color is an ongoing hallucination, and since it characterizes almost all of our visual experience, we live in a continual hallucination.

Comment: @jobermark There is a wavelength of yellow which is can be created by combining wavelengths of other colours, it's just that we don't have cones in our retina to pick it up, we only have long, medium and short wavelength receptors anything that falls in between is made up from the signals from these. In this case we are "deducing" a colour that actually does exist (other devices can distinguish it), we just didn't sense it properly. You're absolutely right, of course, about so much of what we sense being some form of hallucination, but this appears to be more of a counter-example.

Comment: I don't mean to be deliberately pedantic, I just think you made a very good point, and I didn't want it to be detracted from by a slightly flawed example. The way we put seamless images together from what is actually a constantly changing set of pictures every time we move our eye, or the way we invent the colours in our peripheral vision (which has no colour receptors) would be genuine hallucinations of something which might not actually exist in the real world.

Comment: The fact that "there is no discontinuous point where something is 'just unrealistic enough' to be a hallucination" is key to the question, I think because even a machine must make inferences from the electrical signals it is getting from its sensory devices and so is prone to the same problem, a scale where the bigger the inference, the more likely it is to make a mistake (hallucinate), but no discrete point at which it turns from one to the other.

Comment: @Isaacson  There is still none of that wavelength of light present in the combination of red and green light that humans perceive as yellow.  We are taking two different signals and interpolating a third.  We imagine there is yellow light where there is no individual photon of the color yellow.  I guess unless one is pedantic about the definition of a color, this example falls apart.  But I wanted something perfectly normal that is actually fake.

Comment: This is a characteristic of normal processing: there is so much guessing that we make stuff up.  We see lights move in the dark, we imagine cars moving when instead we move relative to them, etc.  There is not enough clarity for us to determine what are normal illusions and what are 'hallucinations'.  The same is true of any computer system scanning its environment assiduously enough, whether or not it is AI.  At some level of complexity, the corrections for potential noise necessarily create false impressions.  So the question falls apart well before we get to questions of intelligence.

Comment: @Jobermark I see what you mean now, I had taken your example to mean subtractive combination i.e pigment action on white light which would have resulted in a genuine 575nm reflection of yellow light. We still would have to infer this colour as our eyes do not have cones sensitive to that frequency, still an hallucination, but one which tells us something more "real" than we can detect rather than less "real". But you were referring to additive combination of light, so your example makes sense to me now.

Comment: I've edited my answer to take account of your comments, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an article about AI image hallucinations:

[**Yes, androids do dream of electric sheep**](https://www.theguardian.com/technology/2015/jun/18/google-image-recognition-neural-network-androids-dream-electric-sheep) (The Guardian, 18 June 2015)

If a program can see hallucinations it could also attempt to interact with them.  With some coaxing I imagine it could maintain a hallucinatory narrative.

*Google frees its dream robots: half eaten doughnut. Illustration: Google*

[image]

Comment: Interesting. So it seems my suspicions of some AIers claiming their machines could dream was not entirely unfounded. From the image you posted and those in the article, fractals seem to be the theme of recognition. Like it recognized one element and then looks for that element at different scales in the image. Seems to be a caterpillar above and them it emphasizes the curve of that at various scales and rotations. But you may note my earlier example of hallucination was output in the absence of input and we are definitely getting input here.

Answer (score 0):

Hallucination in the sense of seeing things that are not actually there takes place all the time, we "see" colours by deduction from frequencies near to those colours, we also see an uninterrupted image of the world around us despite it being constructed from hundreds of constantly changing images. Broadly our brain's activity in response to visual stimuli can be divided into three types, those which use our limited sensory equipment to deduce something about the world which is real (detectable by other equipment) but which we have not actually seen, those which help to create a useful picture of the world which most others would agree with but which might not actually be there (optical illusions etc) and those where information from our memories or imagination get mis-identified as coming from our eyes.

An AI will by necessity suffer from the first type of hallucination unless their input systems are so advanced as to accurately receive all signals in the entire range of wavelengths from all sources. The second type will also be a necessity as the machine would be unlikely to function efficiently without some degree of inference where it's sensors are lacking.

Only in the third type do I think it is relevant exactly how the machine is manufactured

Hallucination in response to sensory deprivation is not an indicator of a "subjective experience or reality" it's just the way our brains are wired. All our sensory experiences, whether real, remembered or imagined are processed using the same part of the brain. Normally a second part of the brain provides us with information about the source of the sense, in the absence of evidence (sensory isolation) or in cases of Schizophrenia, it cannot do this and we mis-identify internally generated sensory experiences as external ones, see [here](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/19829208).

So if an AI was wired to process sensory data in the same way (i.e, sometimes from its external sensors, sometimes from its memory banks, or its pattern-generating circuits, but with a subsequent program to tell it which) in the absence of that subsequent program, it may (if it were programmed to do so) decide that all sources of sensory data are probably external and so "hallucinate". It would not be difficult to make a machine generate the same data from its memory as it is generating from it sensory input devices and treat them as identically sourced.

The trouble with AI/conciousness type discussions is that we are speculating on a technology that does not exist and so that technology could theoretically do anything. We do not need a physicalist understanding of reality to speculate about AI conciousness because even if we accept a dualist perspective, why would we then dismiss the idea that technology could advance to the stage where it could be programmed to access the "realm of ideas"?

If we're going to accept the idea of a technology being able to do something it currently can't, what rational reason could there be to the deliberately constrain the ability of that technology and then claim to have discovered something interesting by doing so?

Comment: Research in AI has been for the 'simulation' of consciousness. Humans can only experience their own consciousness. They can try to understand how other humans understand their consciousness through the watered down medium of language. Currently the theories are: its all material, it all immaterial and its a mix of both. Possible currently AI research is trying to realize the reality of physical consciousness.

Comment: @AnoopAlex What makes you think that humans can only understand the concious experience of other humans through language? Does not neuroscience and physiological experimentation provide us with insights also? Either way it is still nothing more than speculation, to say the current theories are "its all material, it all immaterial and its a mix of both" is a very generous interpretation. To me, that just sounds like a list of all the possibilities. If we didn't know whether a box contains sand or water it would not be a useful insight to say it might be sand or water or both.

Comment: Until we knew definitively whether it was sand or water, saying it might be sand or water or both WOULD be the best explanation. And if our entire world was made of sand and we were only aware of the concept of water we might make the mistake of only looking at methods that would prove it was sand and ignoring ones that would prove it was water.

Comment: Sorry, I think my metaphor might not have been very well expressed, imagine the same scenario in a world, as you say, made up entirely of sand and water, then to say it is either sand, water or both would be entirely correct, but not *useful*. We are not in danger of ignoring one option simply because no-one has said it is a possibility, so I don't see the utility of the statement.

Comment: You seem to be confusing the neural representation of sensation with the experience of sensation. As Morten Overgaard points out, neuroscience relies on subjective accounts to gain insight into conscious experience: "To arrive at this association [with consciousness], one would have to conduct several experiments correlating recurrent processes with consciousness—using introspecting experimental participants. Consequently, this method would not be independent of introspection but would carry the strengths, weaknesses, and limitations of introspection."

Comment: @PedeLeao What makes you think the neural representation of sensation and the experience of sensation are two different things? Also, neuroscience does not *rely* on subjective accounts, it can deduce a number of objective statements from observations of brain activity which broadly correlates across a wide range of subjects, and through studies of brain damage, can infer a considerable amount of objective information about sensation. Overgaard is simply presuming conciousness is a certain kind of thing and then making statements about how it could be investigated based on that presumption.

Comment: Except that's simply not true. They can only deduce such things because they did correlate the data with subjective accounts just as Overgaard says. He's a professor of neuroscience from Aarhus University, and you're just speculating about things you know nothing about.

Comment: @Isaacson Are you saying that science is not ignoring non-materialistic theories of consciousness?I have read very little on biocentrism but the little I have seems to imply it is a radical theory based on quantum science to explain consciousness. There does not seem to have been interest pursuing it further.

Comment: @PedeLeao Are you saying "subjective accounts" are the same as "introspection"? Wouldn't it be possible to monitor a subject's  brain activity by presenting commonly accepted positive/negative sense data without asking for their subjective accounts? Ofcourse I dont know if such tests have been done....

Comment: @AnoopAlex. Overgaard's point is that such evidence is ultimately dependent upon that of introspection and not the other way around. Even if a scan might give a high degree of probability that an experience is occurring, the best evidence remains a personal account of the experience. Concerning hallucinations: Information can't be said to have an existence dependent on any particular substrate, so it lacks the ontological qualifications to exhibit phenomenal properties. Any opinion to the contrary is due to nothing more than wishful thinking.

Comment: @PedeLeao I can agree with that. Introspection may not be dependent for the communication of an experience but for the experience itself. Mapping signals in the brain to activity gives information about ongoing processes but that does not necessarily make them the experience itself as some popular writers like Dennett claim. The map is not the territory. That theory may work if actual matter for thought has been found as Tegmark claims.

Comment: @AnoopAlex Yes, science is not ignoring non-materialistic theories, it's just that science needs a falsifiable theory in order to be science, a non-materialistic explanation cannot be measured and so cannot be falsified. The point is that non-materialism is just materialism that's currently beyond our technology to detect, when it is no longer beyond us to detect it, we will no doubt measure and test theories about it.

Comment: @PedeLeao Firstly, ad hominem arguments are not helpful here, you do not know what I know or don't know about. Secondly, just because Overgaard is a professor of neuroscience does not mean everything he says is right, there are other professors of neuroscience in the world and plenty disagree with his analysis. Being a professor of neuroscience does not automatically make one the final arbiter of what is subjective, or what the limits of knowledge are. If you have a rational argument, please present it so that everyone else has the benefit of reading it rather than just appealing to authority.

Comment: @Isaacson. You can take it personal if you like, but your answer gives me no reason to believe that you are doing anything more than speculating. The original intention of this site was to maintain a level of quality which your answer lacks. You flat out contradicted a neuroscientist without a single reference. Can you do something to improve your answer?

Comment: @PédeLeão  Being reasonable within itself and grounded in pretty widely accepted science is a reason to believe the author is not speculating.  Giving a citation that actually says what he answer contains is a reason to believe the author is not speculating.  Are you insisting he has done neither of those things?  The level of quality can always be raised, but this is not an evaluation it is a blatantly false attack.  The people on which he bases these notions *are* to some degree speculating -- but that is part of their job.  And their speculations are tested wtih data.

Comment: @PedeLeao Perhaps it would help if you could specify which statement in my answer requires further citation. By my judgement, I've made two statements on which the argument is based,1) that hallucination is a mis-identification of internal sensory experience, which I have referenced with a study. 2) that the technology to create an hallucinating AI does not currently exist, which I presume is so obvious as to not need citation. The rest is just reasoned induction from those premises. I'm not clear what you would like a citation to support.